# Create column for sum of total revenue as well monthly revenue. using group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create column with Monthly total as well column for total per VIN .Kindly Help to get the output dataframe..

```
Final_Data = pd.DataFrame(Final_Data.groupby(by='VIN'
                        as_index=False, ,'Month')['Dealers_Revenue'].sum())
```

current dataframe
Final_Data:

| VIN | Revenue | Category | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v1 | 30 | MKL | 64 |
| v1 | 50 | GKL | 64 |
| v1 | 40 | GKL | 64 |
| v1 | 30 | UKL | 63 |
| v1 | 40 | MKL | 63 |
| v2 | 30 | MKL | 63 |
| v2 | 50 | GKL | 63 |
| v2 | 40 | GKL | 62 |
| v2 | 30 | UKL | 62 |
| v2 | 40 | MKL | 61 |

Output I want in dataframe
Final_Data:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? Why are there missing cells in output? Please take a [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: You wrote 50 instead of 40 in the last column of Total Revenue by Month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'VIN':['v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2'],
    'Revenue':[30, 50, 40, 30, 40, 30, 50, 40, 30, 50], 
    'Category':['MKL', 'GKL','GKL', 'UKL', 'MKL', 'MKL', 'GKL', 'GKL', 'UKL', 'MKL'],
    'Month':[64, 64, 64, 63, 63, 63, 63, 62, 62, 61]
})

print(df)

  VIN  Revenue Category  Month
0  v1       30      MKL     64
1  v1       50      GKL     64
2  v1       40      GKL     64
3  v1       30      UKL     63
4  v1       40      MKL     63
5  v2       30      MKL     63
6  v2       50      GKL     63
7  v2       40      GKL     62
8  v2       30      UKL     62
9  v2       50      MKL     61
```

```
# revenue sum by VIN and Month 
df_group = df.groupby(['VIN','Month']).agg(list).reset_index()

print(df_group)

  VIN  Month       Revenue         Category
0  v1     63      [30, 40]       [UKL, MKL]
1  v1     64  [30, 50, 40]  [MKL, GKL, GKL]
2  v2     61          [50]            [MKL]
3  v2     62      [40, 30]       [GKL, UKL]
4  v2     63      [30, 50]       [MKL, GKL]
```

```
# calculate total revenue by VIN
df_tot = df_group.groupby(['VIN'])['Revenue'].sum().reset_index()

print(df_tot)

VIN               Revenue
0  v1  [30, 40, 30, 50, 40]
1  v2  [50, 40, 30, 30, 50]
```

```
# merge df_group with df_tot and rename columns
df_merge = pd.merge(df_group, df_tot, on='VIN').rename(columns={'Revenue_x': 'Total Revenue by Month', 'Revenue_y': 'Total Revenue by VIN'})

# sum lists
df_merge['Total Revenue by Month'] = df_merge['Total Revenue by Month'].apply(sum)
df_merge['Total Revenue by VIN'] = df_merge['Total Revenue by VIN'].apply(sum)

print(df_merge)

  VIN  Month  Total Revenue by Month         Category  Total Revenue by VIN
0  v1     63                      70       [UKL, MKL]                   190
1  v1     64                     120  [MKL, GKL, GKL]                   190
2  v2     61                      50            [MKL]                   200
3  v2     62                      70       [GKL, UKL]                   200
4  v2     63                      80       [MKL, GKL]                   200
```

Comment: Hello.. I tried ur code & its absolutely correct i just wanna say is thr any way out that i can get all the column in the output Df??

Comment: This is the best I could do

Comment: Hello!! can u even help me with extracting VIN row where Month is smaller than equal to 61 greater than equal to 63.. basically defining a upper and lower bound..

Comment: I even tried this code : df_merge = df_merge[(df_merge['Month'].clip(61,63))]

Comment: `df_merge[(df_merge['Month'] == df_merge['Month'].min()) | (df_merge['Month'] == df_merge['Month'].max())]`